# Как сделать меню посередине?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать - всё перепробовал. У меня вот такой код:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/widget_logo.gif">
<table align='center' width='26%'>
<tr>
<td colspan='0'><img src="/images/В online.png" type="images" class="SuperImages" />
</td>
</tr>
<td>
<tr>

<div class="menu">
<a href="/">Главная</a> |
<a href="/feed.php">Новости</a> |
<a href="/photo.php">Фотогравии</a> |
<a href="../bkock/офф сайт">Офф. сайт О.А.Андреевича</a> |
<a href="o_site.php">О сайте</a> |
<a href="login.php">Выход</a> |
</div>

</td>
</tr>
<table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<tr> <td colspan='0'><img src="/images/В online.png" type="images" class="SuperImages" /> </td> </tr> <tr> <td>
```

У вас тег <td> идет перед <tr>, а нужно так <tr><td>

Comment: понятно!! щяс сделаю!

Comment: @d1b2 держите нас в курсе событий!

Answer (score 1):

1 способ - добавить тег <center>
2 способ - css: margin:0 auto;
3 способ - align="center"